# adding date in calendar instance time zone is changing from EST TO EDT in android

Tags: java, android

I am adding a date in a calendar instance to check dst while adding a date eg 08-03-2014 to 09-03-2014 time zone is changing from EST TO EDT. The day light time is returning false.

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("us/alaska");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeZone(tz);             

c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
checkDayLightTime = tz.inDaylightTime(c.getTime());
System.out.println("current get time"+c.getTime());
System.out.println("checkDayLightTime"+checkDayLightTime);    

03-08 02:59:58.505: INFO/System.out(12092): current get timeSun Mar 09 03:59:58 EDT 2014
03-08 02:59:58.505: INFO/System.out(12092): checkDayLightTimefalse
```

Comment: when did it print that you are using the EST? Also post the whole code where you initialized time zone and calendar

Comment: why did you got march when you add 1?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin In Device I set the date as  Mar 8 2014

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with you result `EDT` means that `EST` are currently in daylight. Actually `Mar 08` is still in standard time and `Mar 09` is in daylight saving time.

Some facts about **EST**:

```
Only some locations are currently on EST, because most places in this time zone are currently on Daylight Saving Time.
Locations that are on EST part of the year are currently on EDT (Eastern Daylight Time).
```

Comment: but it is displaying false instead of true if day ligh saving is on

Comment: @mohan on mine yea it displaying true even if tz is added